# Any workaround to set PATH for debugger (VS 2017, 2019, toolset v141)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

In Visual Studio 2017/2019, in a c++ project, project property pages / configuration properties / debugging / environment, we set environment to a certain value, but it is ignored (it does not work) when we use toolset v141, and it works with v142 (VS2019 only).

Is there any way to set a certain `$env:path` for the debugger, in a specific configuration (debug/release) ?

I thought about running a command before the `Command = $(TargetPath)`, but it's not straightforward.

[image]

Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/549114/project-propertiesenvironmentpath-being-ignored-by.html